# How do i execute specific sections only automatically?

Tags: matlab, sections

I want to write a script that automatically executes specific sections of a the script and skips all other sections.
Here's my example code:

```
clear all; close all; clc;

to_plot=input('Which values do you want to plot: ','s');
x=linspace(0,100);

%% SECTION 1
y1=x;
figure('Position', [100, 100, 1024, 768]);
plot(x,y1);

print( gcf, '-dpng', 'y1.png');

%% SECTION 2
y2=x.^2
figure('Position',[100, 100, 1024, 768]);
plot(x,y2);

print( gcf, '-dpng','y2.png');

%% SECTION 3
y3=x.^3
figure('Position',[100, 100, 1024, 768]);
plot(x,y3);

print( gcf, '-dpng','y3.png');
```

Now i want to be able to make an input like `to_plot=y1,y3` and the script automatically only executes the 1st and 3rd section and just skips the 2nd and all (possible) other sections. Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this Without adding an `if`-condition to each section?
EDIT: And if someone feels like making me really happy, he or she could add a checkbox menu in which I can check all the values i want to plot.

Comment: Use an `if` statement...

Comment: You could turn your script into a function that takes an array of the steps that you want to use. Use conditional statements to execute only the steps contained in the input array.

Comment: Yes, I thought about that, but i thought there might be a more gallant way of doing it

Comment: I guess everybody is assuming this is not your actual code, because if it were you would just need to pass `1, 2, or 3` as an argument to a single function with no `if` statements.

Comment: no of course it's not my actual code. My actual code is way longer, but this serves quite good as an example i guess. But what to you mean by "pass 1,2 or 3 as an argument to a single function with no if statements"?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest is probably to use [`if`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/if.html) statements. Here I use [`str2num`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2num.html) to convert the output of [`input`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/input.html) to a vector of numbers. I then use [`any`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/any.html) to check if the value we want is contained within the returned vector from [`str2num`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2num.html).

```
plotting = str2num(input('Which values do you want to plot? ', 's'));

if (any(plotting == 1))
    fprintf(1, 'Plot y1\n');
end

if (any(plotting == 2))
    fprintf(1, 'Plot y2\n');
end

if (any(plotting == 3))
    fprintf(1, 'Plot y3\n');
end
```

Sample outputs for the above would be

```
>> plotting_fun
Which values do you want to plot? 1 3
Plot y1
Plot y3

>> plotting_fun
Which values do you want to plot? 1,3
Plot y1
Plot y3
```

---

As a side note, I like `any` because it can be used to make your code really easy to read.

> It does what it says on the tin!

Comment: Yes, the `any` is awesome and might be helpful for me later, since you don't have to give in the parameters in the right order. Upvote for that. But apart from that i would prefer solving the problem without if-statements, as i mentioned above

Comment: @Max - You can't do it dynamically without `if/else` statements.  Basically, you want to change the contents of the file when `to_plot` is entered in so that only certain portions of the file get executed.  From what I know, MATLAB does not have what you are looking for.... unless I'm proven wrong.

Comment: @rayryeng So let's hope you will get proven wrong. But thanks for the information, I'm afraid you are right.

Comment: @Max - If I am proven wrong here, I'll be very happy because this is a rather curious feature and would like to see if there is such support for it... nevertheless, good luck!

Comment: @Max Do you know of any language that can change its flow of control without `if`, `switch`, etc? I just don't see how you can execute certain parts of code without using `if`, `switch`, etc.

Comment: I'm not a programmer, I just have a little experience in Matlab and Java, but I'm not a professional. So how would I know, if that's possible or not? That's exactly why I asked it here. And if you all tell me, it's impossible than i have to do it another way. But i thought it would be possible, since Matlab gives you the opportunity to run a single section manually, so the only thing, that is missing is something to do that automatically

Comment: Running single sections is part of the MATLAB editor.  That can only be done by writing a MATLAB script file, and all it does is batch executes each line of code in between `%%` statements.  There isn't a way to dynamically run certain sections based on user input in the way you are speaking... you need `if/else` statements for that for sure.

Comment: @Max <strike>You may be able to force MATLAB to run a section manually depending on the input but it would still require an `if` statement.</strike> If Ray says it can't be done, thats enough for me! My previous question was also genuine as I would be delighted to find a new language that could do that.